# Edit a script DOM element before being executed

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I'm currently using Selenium WebDrivers for my tests and I'm struggling with an automatic download. The case is:
I click on a button, it loads the next page containing a script tag with a `click()` on a download link.

Is it possible to edit the script tag (or even delete it) before the full page loading, and avoiding this click and so, the automatic download ? I want to manually download it. It permits me to have one single solution, and not one auto download disable configuration for each browser .....

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can execute Javascript [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java). Of course, implementation may vary depending on the language you're using.

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
}
```

In your case, the Javascript will look something like this. Example [as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708189/remove-specific-script-tag-in-head-tag-by-onclick-event):

```
document.getElementById("testScriptName")).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
```

**EDIT**:
Something worth looking into: if you're using C#, you can use FiddlerCore to intercept a request:
http://chowson.github.io/block-requests-with-fiddlercore/

Basically, you'll use the `BeforeRequest` event handler to see if this request is for the particular script. If so, then you fake the response.

Comment: I used JavascriptExecutor but the DOM modification seems to be applied after the script execution. I can see that my script tag is empty but the auto download popup still showed off. For the moment it's not blocking, it's a 'dev' page so I removed the auto download from the source page. But I'm curious to know if it's possible with JS though

Comment: @buzz2buzz See my edit - FiddlerCore might offer a solution.